# Not a statement? (Bluej)

Tags: java, bluej

So the program i question is supposed to be really simple, take three inputted numbers, and multiply them by itself and display the result, only, Bluej insists that each time I ask it to multiply, it's not a statement. (Tbf, i'm new in the java business, so i still might be 100% wrong)

```
private static double Square ( int num1, int num2, int num3) {

    if ( num1 > 0) {
        num1 * num1;
        System.out.println (num1);
    } else {
        System.out.println( "Enter a correct number, please.");
    }

    if ( num2 > 0) { 
        num2 * num2;
        System.out.println (num2); 
    } else {
        System.out.println("Really? Again. Do the right thing this time, jeez.");
    }

    if ( num3 > 0) {
        num3*num3;
        System.out.println (num3);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Just make it more then one!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: `num1 *= num1;` or `num1 = num1 * num1;`

Comment: Sorry, but what does num1 *= num1; mean?

Comment: it means exactly the same as `num1 = num1 * num1;`

Comment: What he is saying is you have num1 * num1; and so on. What you need is num1 = num1 * num1; Let's look at it like this -> position 1 = position 2  * position 3;   This translate to take the variable in position 2 and multiply it by variable in position 3. Take the answer from multiplying and store it into variable in position 1. So basically, multiply the same number twice. Clear the variable num1 and now store the answer into it.

Comment: Also static double should be static void because you are not returning any doubles. You are just printing to screen. How would you know if you are returning anything you ask? You will know because you will use the keyword "return" and you are not using that keyword. <-This is not true in all cases. <-This statement is not for you. It's for the people who are going to get on my case for making the previous statement.

Comment: Why does num1, num2, and num3 have to be greater than zero? Is that part of the assignment requirements. If not remove those conditions.

Comment: I think you could just write `System.out.println (num1 * num1);` (and so on for the others).  You don't actually need to _change_ the value of `num1`.

Comment: Wow, there are a lot of alternatives here. static double has to stay, or else i get a error w/ previous code, it's required to be above 0, and David, would you mind explaining how changing values and i guess, 'faking' a change goes on? or is there a fourm/FAQ i can read abt that somewhere

Answer (score 1):

I think it's been Like this.

## code

```
private static double Square ( int num1, int num2, int num3) {
        
    if ( num1 > 0 && num2 > 0 && num3 > 0) {
        num1 *= num1;
        num2 *= num2;
        num3 *= num3;
        System.out.println (num1);
        System.out.println (num2);
        System.out.println (num3);
    } else {
        System.out.println( "Enter positive numbers please.");
    }       
    return 0;    
}
```

OR you can do like this also.

## code

```
private static double Square ( int num1, int num2, int num3) {
        
    if ( num1 > 0 && num2 > 0 && num3 > 0) {
                    
        System.out.println (num1*num1);
        System.out.println (num2*num2);
        System.out.println (num3*num3);
    } else {
        System.out.println( "Enter positive numbers please.");
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: can you Tell Me why it won't?

Comment: Static double with no return statement.

Answer (score 0):

You always need to return double
even if it's 0.0